# Docker container run through Rancher don't have IP

Tags: docker, rancher, traefik

I use traefik on my server to load balances my apps with a docker backend.
I started rancher (1.6.14) through docker to start other app easily.

I succeed to access to rancher through traefik. But when I start an app through rancher, the containers don't have an IP so traefik can't contact them. In the traefik backend I see `http://:8000` for my app with the stack:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: mykiwi/ttrss
    labels:
      traefik.port: 8000
      traefik.protocol: http
      traefik.frontend.entryPoints: https
      traefik.frontend.rule: Host:foo.bar

  database:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=ttrss
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ttrss
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  database: ~
```

Any idea why / how to fix this ?
I also tried to add this: (inspired by wekan config)

rancher-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    scale: 1
    retain_ip: true
    start_on_create: true

  database:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
```

Same result.

Answer (score 0):

When containers are launched via Rancher, they are part of Rancher's "managed" network. The containers do get an IP address, but it's from a different network(default: 10.42.0.0/16), not the docker network (172.17.0.0/16).

Rancher also has a loadbalancer service that can take care of the application needs. Please check: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/cattle/adding-load-balancers/#adding-a-load-balancer-in-the-ui for more information.